# Where does Asterisk safe wether or not the Voicemail is active

Tags: asterisk

I want to create a Web form to manage Asterisk. I want to be able to turn the Voicemail on and off, and see if it is active or not.

Where does Asterisk save this information?

Thanks

Comment: You can look at Freepbx, which already do that. http://serverfault.com/questions/607111/how-do-i-activate-voicemail-on-an-extension-on-asterisk-freepbx http://astbook.asteriskdocs.org/en/2nd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-APP-D-SECT-41.html

Comment: What do you mean by turn voicemail on & off? system wide, or just for one user? What have you done to research this?Have you tested anything ?

Answer (score 0):

On extensions.conf, you call `VoiceMail` function to record the voicemail.
Use `IF` statement to turn on/off voice mail function.

The condition of the "IF" is ip to you.
You can use config file which is editable by httpd user to set variables or use mysql to retrieve the status.

[Asterisk:The Definitive Guide](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/)  is very good source to learn how to do so.